# Prove if $b\neq x^2a$ then $\sqrt{b}\notin F(\sqrt{a})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove if $b\neq x^2a$ then $\sqrt{b}\notin F(\sqrt{a})$. Conclude that $F(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$ is of degree 4 over $F$.

Suppose $b=x^2a$ then $\sqrt{b}=x\sqrt{a}$ meaning $\sqrt{b}\in F(\sqrt{a})$, however since our original hypothesis says $b\neq x^2a$ then this cannot be true. I'm sure there's another way to approach this, but I don't know?

Comment: You've shown that $b = x^2 a$ implies $\sqrt{b}\in F(\sqrt{a})$, which is not what you were trying to prove.

Comment: We if $b$ cannot be $x^2a$ then $\sqrt{b}$ won't be in $F(\sqrt{a})$. Maybe I should try a proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

If $$\sqrt{b}=x+y\sqrt{a}$$ then

$$b=x^2+y^2a+2xy\sqrt{a}$$

Assuming that $\sqrt{a}\not\in F$ and $\sqrt{b}\not\in F$ we must have $x=0$. Thus 
$$\sqrt{b}=y\sqrt{a}$$

Comment: Does this conclude that $b\neq x^2a$?

Comment: Well I am showing if $\sqrt{b}\in F(\sqrt{a})$ then $b=y^2a$.

Comment: I do not understand how this helps prove $b\neq x^2a$

Comment: For it proves the contrapositive.